# How to change directory in "Publish over SSH plugin" in Jenkins

Tags: windows, ssh, deployment, jenkins, build

I'm using Jenkins' Publish Over SSH plugin to deploy my builds to a windows machine which has SSH server running. Issue is that I need to deploy the build into E Drive of the target system, but when I try to give E drive location in the "Remote Directory" box of the plugin, it throws Exception as "Unable to change" directory.

[Jenkins Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bzS3.png)

Comment: Does Jenkins use its own ssh server, or do you have one already there, like from Cygwin?  If it's cygwin the location of the E drive would be `/cygdrive/e/`

Comment: Jenkins uses its own SSH server and it needs one on the target machine..... and I'm not using Cygwin...

Answer (score 1):

Finally got a solution: 
To use a directory name with : in it use this notation:

like "E:\Test"  use this

/E=/Test/

Update: after comments from @"Brian Ogden"

/E:Test/

Comment: For me this didn't work. Instead i had to use:
/E\:Test/

Comment: @geld0r You're right.... my QA recently reported that against 2012 server my syntax didn't work and he had to do the same what you've suggested....

Comment: @Brian Ogden, by mistake I rejected your suggest, sorry about that